# Articles with plural and uncountable nouns

Tags: articles

Is it necessary to include a definite article or the words "some" and "any" in questions and negations with plural and uncountable nouns? Let's consider the following scenarios:

1) I'm on the phone with my brother, talking about his roadtrip. Can I simply ask:

> Can you see mountains already?

Or should I add a determiner before the noun? For whatever reason this one doesn't sound as idiomatic as its slightly longer version:

> Can you see mountains in the distance?

2) I'm at a supermarket. I'm calling my wife and ask her:

> Do we need milk?

Again, is the determiner needed? And how is this different from:

> Do we need any milk?

3)

> I don't hang out with celebrities, nor do I need fame.

How does the sentence change if I add the determiners:

> I don't hang out with any celebrities, nor do I need any fame.

4) Why does it seem okay to state:

> Thank you, but I don't like wine.

But in the following clause, removing "any" seems wrong?

> Thank you, I don't want any wine.

But then again, this sentence seems perfectly fine. Or perhaps it doesn't?

> I don't have kids and do not want to have any.

Comment: The determiners can be freely omitted.

Comment: The only example where **any** is needed before the noun is when refusing the offer of wine, since "I don't want wine" might be understood to mean "I would like a different beverage".

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "yes and no".  Sometimes you may omit the article or any determiner, and sometimes you shouldn't.  For example:

> (On a telephone call) "Hey, I'm on my way to you but I'm lost.  Which way do I go?"
>
> "Well, look around.  Can you see **(any) mountains**?"
>
> "Yes, they're off to my right"
>
> "Good, then just head toward **the mountains** and then turn left at **the gas station**.  Go up the dirt track until you see **(some) large rocks**.  That's where we are camped.

I can't seem to find any rule about this, but it seems that if you have a *generic* plural or uncountable noun you don't need any determiner. The "some" or "any" is implied, if it could be used in that context.  Otherwise you do need a determiner of some kind.

This also seems to depend more on the verb used than the context:

> I don't like wine
>
> I don't drink tea

With these, you would not say "any".  On the other hand:

> I don't want (any) wine
>
> She doesn't eat (any) fish
>
> They don't hang out with (any) comedians.

With these, the "any" is not necessary -- if you leave it out, it is implied.

However, the scope of the sentence might change if you use "some" or "any". "Wine" might refer to wine *in general* while "any wine" might refer to the bottle you're being offered.  "I don't hang out with comedians" is a very broad statement that implies you *would never* socialize with comedians, while "I don't hang out with *any* comedians" suggests that's just the current situation, but I have nothing against comedians in general.

If you deliberately omit the determiner, it can make the sentence a more powerful statement.  For example an actor might say

> "I don't do comedies"

to imply he doesn't do them *at all*, but say

> "I don't do any comedies"

to imply he doesn't do them *at present*.

In a similar way, "Thank you, I don't want wine" is a strong statement, like you *would never* drink wine, or (depending on intonation) that you would prefer something else.  "I don't want any wine" simply suggests you don't feel like it *at the moment*.

I'm afraid this might be another of those English situations where you have to learn from experience.

Comment: Okay, so the determiners in the brackets are optional - they can be freely omitted, right?

Comment: And what do you think is a differece betwren "I don't have friends", and, at least to my ear, more idiomatic "I don't have any friends"?

Comment: @BebopB.yes determiners in brackets can be omitted.  I don't think there's any difference between "I don't have any friends" and "I don't have friends".  In cases where there is a difference it might be subtle, and depend entirely on intonation and context.  I wish I could give you a simple rule to follow :(